# Using data from tables in a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

**names:**

```
id,  first,     last

879  Scotty     Anderson
549  Melvin     Anderson
554  Freddy     Appleton
321  Grace      Appleton
112  Milton     Appleton
189  Jackson    Black
 99  Elizabeth  Black
298  Jordan     Frey
```

**parents:**

```
id,  student_id
549  879
321  554
112  554
 99  189
298  189
```

### Expected Output

(without the 'Student:' / 'Parent:')

```
Student: Anderson, Scotty
 Parent: Anderson, Melvin

Student: Appleton, Freddy
 Parent: Appleton, Grace
 Parent: Appleton, Milton

Student: Black, Jackson
 Parent: Black, Elizabeth
 Parent: Frey, Jordan
```

Using the data above, how can I achieve the expected output?

I currently use SQL similar to this to get a list of current students and names.

```
select b.last, b.first
  from term a, names b
 where a.id = b.id(+)
 order by b.last
```

Which returns:

```
Anderson, Scotty
Appleton, Freddy
Black, Jackson
```

My question is how to take the `parents` table and add to this query so it has this output:

```
Anderson, Scotty
Anderson, Melvin
Appleton, Freddy
Appleton, Grace
Appleton, Milton
Black, Jackson
Black, Elizabeth
Frey, Jordan
```

Comment: Are you using `mySQL` or `Oracle` RDBMS?

Comment: Oracle. But I'd like to know the general logic for any SQL syntax.

Comment: Typically you solve that by a join and getting a sligthly exploded table, then you use programming to format it. (You can also do it in SQL but then its not generic) `select p.first,p.last,s.first.s.last from names p,names s,parents where p.id = parents.id and s.id=parents.student_id sort by 1,2,3,4`.

Answer (score 1):

generic SQL, mmmmm I'd like there to be A generic SQL :)

First off you want to stop using the antique (+) join syntax that is exclusive to Oracle

```
select b.last, b.first
  from term a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN names b ON a.id = b.id
  order by b.last
```

That is way more generic! (nb: You can abbreviate to just LEFT JOIN)

Now to concatenate (Last Name comma space First Name) there are options some not generic

**SQL Server/MySQL and others supporting CONCAT()**

```
select CONCAT(b.last , ', ', b.first)
  from term a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN names b ON a.id = b.id
  order by b.last
```

not all versions of Oracle or SQL Server support CONCAT()
Oracle's concat() only takes 2 parameters; grrrrr

**ORACLE**

```
select b.last || ', ' || b.first
  from term a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN names b ON a.id = b.id
  order by b.last
```

In this form Oracle generally handles data type conversions automatically (I think, please check on date/timestamps maybe others)

**TSQL (Sybase, MS SQL Server)**

```
select b.last + ', ' + b.first
  from term a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN names b ON a.id = b.id
  order by b.last
```

In this form you must explicitly cast/convert data types to n|var|char for concatenation if not already a string type

---

For your list of concatenated names:
You need in addition to the last name a method to retain the family group together, plus distinguish between student and parent. As you want just one column of names this indicates you need a column of id's that point to the last and first names. So making some assumptions about the table `TERM` my guess is you list the students from that, then append the parents that relate to that group of students, and finally to output the required list in the required order.

```
select
      case when type = 1 then 'Student' else 'Parent' end as who
    , names.last || ', ' || names.first as Name
from (
      select
            STUDENT_ID     as name_id
          , STUDENT_ID     as family_id
          , 1              as TYPE
      from term
      union all
        select
              PARENTS.ID         as name_id
            , PARENTS.STUDENT_ID as family_id
            , 2                  as TYPE
        from PARENTS
        inner join term on PARENTS.STUDENT_ID = term.STUDENT_ID
    ) sq
inner join NAMES ON sq.name_id = NAMES.ID
order by
      names.last
    , sq.family_id
    , sq.type
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01804/6

Answer (score 1):

The idea in a query like this is to break the data down into something that helps you solve the problem, and then put it back together as needed. In this case I'm going to make use of common table expressions, which allows me to treat queries as tables and then recombine them handily.

Looking at the desired results it looks like we want to have the students appear first, followed by their mothers (ladies first :-), and then their fathers. So, OK, let's figure out how to extract the needed data. We can get the students and their associated data pretty simply:

```
select distinct p.student_id as student_id,
                n.first,
                n.last,
                0 as type
  from parents p
  inner join names n
  on n.id = p.student_id
```

The `type` column, with its constant value of zero, is just used to identify that this is a student. (You'll see why in a minute).

Now, getting the mother's is a bit more difficult because we don't have any gender information to use. However, we'll use what we have, which is names. We know that names like Melvin, Milton, and Jordan are "guy" names. (Yes, I know Jordan can be a girls name too. My daughter has a male coach named Jordan, and a female teammate named Jordan. Just go with it - for purposes of argument in this case Jordan is a guys name, 'K? 'K :-). So we'll use that information to help us identify the mom's:

```
select p.student_id, n.first, n.last, 1 as type
  from parents p
  inner join names n
    on n.id = p.id
  where first not in ('Melvin', 'Milton', 'Jordan')
```

Notice here that we assign the value of 1 to the `type` column for mothers.

Similarly, we'll find the dads:

```
select p.student_id, n.first, n.last, 2 as type
  from parents p
  inner join names n
    on n.id = p.id
  where first in ('Melvin', 'Milton', 'Jordan')
```

And here we assign a value of 2 for the type.

OK - given the above we just need to combine the data properly. We don't want to use a JOIN, however, because we want the names to get spit out one after the other from the query - and the way we do THAT in SQL is with the `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operator. (Generally, you're going to want to use `UNION ALL`, because `UNION` will check the result set to ensure there are no duplicates - which in the case of a large result set takes, oh, more or less FOREVER!). And so, the final query looks like:

```
with all_students as (select distinct p.student_id as student_id,
                                      n.first,
                                      n.last,
                                      0 as type
                        from parents p
                        inner join names n
                        on n.id = p.student_id),
     all_mothers  as (select p.student_id, n.first, n.last, 1 as type
                        from parents p
                        inner join names n
                          on n.id = p.id
                        where first not in ('Melvin', 'Milton', 'Jordan')),
     all_fathers  as (select p.student_id, n.first, n.last, 2 as type
                        from parents p
                        inner join names n
                          on n.id = p.id
                        where first in ('Melvin', 'Milton', 'Jordan'))
select last || ', ' || first as name from 
  (select * from all_students
   union all
   select * from all_mothers
   union all
   select * from all_fathers)
order by student_id desc, type;
```

We just take the student data, followed by the mom data, followed by the dad data, then sort it by the student ID from highest to lowest (I just looked at the desired results to figure out that this should be a descending sort), and then by the type (which results in the student (type=0) being first, following by their mother (type=1) and then their father (type=2)).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21e29/19)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that in SQL:

```
Select last +', '+ first as fullname from names;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Your question doesn't make sense.  The easy answer to the question is:

```
select last, first
from names;
```

But it seems unlikely that is what you want.

Your sample query mentions a table `term`.  That is not mentioned elsewhere in the question.  Please clarify the question or delete this one and ask another.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do. I think you could set up a derived table and then query it. Set up something like: case when student id= id then 1 else 0 as match or whatever. Then query your derived table and group by match.